# I need to unset the state of the jQuery .toggle(odd,even)

Tags: jquery, api, toggle

I have items in a table cell that gets toggled on and off.

An external button accepts a click and submits the selected cell values via ajax.

The problem is that I want to reset the toggle state for the selected cells.

I can easily unset the highlighting, but then need a double click to trigger the correct toggle.

Can the .toggle(odd, even) be reset or cycled via an external call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this by selecting the already toggled list of elements.

I then call a .click on it.

Which seems like a bit of a workaround, but since I can't trigger the state of toggle. I settled for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested but, could it be done like this?

```
//reset the toggle state<br>
      $('#tablecell').unbind('click').toggle(fn1, fn2);<br>
      $('#tablecell').toggle(fn1, fn2);
```

Comment: Unbind and then reset the actual functions?

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle()` is the same as alternating between `.show()` and `.hide()` so just call `.show()` or `.hide()` depending on what the desired "reset" state is.

if you are using `.toggle()` to cycle through handlers then just unbind and rebind the toggle event.

Comment: The problem is that I use toggle in the 2 or more function alternation way.

I then unset via another button and need to programmatically reset the toggle state of the set items.